# Plone 4.1 ConfigurationError - Unknown directive 'expressiontype'

Tags: plone, startup, infinite-loop, buildout

After adding unweb.watermark to eggs, I get an endless series of starts in instance.log (Plone 4.1.2), but no service.

See buildout / fg at http://pastie.org/2776226

How can I investigate/fix this?

Answer (score 2):

By adding that product in a vanilla Plone I've faced these two issues (depending on the versions of products used):

```
ConfigurationError: ('Unknown directive', u'http://namespaces.zope.org/tales', u'expressiontype')
```

or

```
AttributeError: type object 'DirectoryResource' has no attribute
'resource_factories'
```

In order to fix that issue you should extend your buildout like this:

```
[buildout]
...
extends =
    ...
    http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/unweb.watermark/trunk/versions.cfg
    http://good-py.appspot.com/release/plone/4.1.2?dexterity=1.0
```

More info:

- http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/zope/dev/230509
- http://code.google.com/p/dexterity/issues/detail?id=165